# How was that program called that shipped standalone Chrome Dev Tools with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome-devtools, read-eval-print-loop

I remember using a piece of software that provided you with a standalone Dev Tools GUI window with a Node REPL console. It used a three-letter name that started with N. It was a pretty useful tool but I just forgot its name and it is surprisingly ungooglable. Like it's gone from the internet.

Comment: If you're looking to [debug Node you can use use the Chrome dev tools](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ndb](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb). The [original ndb](https://github.com/smtlaissezfaire/ndb) is no longer maintained

> ndb is an improved debugging experience for Node.js, enabled by Chrome DevTools